# Make page variable available in kendoui grid template

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendoui template defined as follows (simplified):

```
<script id="detailsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">

<tr class="row k-alt">
  <td>
        #(OwnerId == userInfo.UserId)? "Me" : OwnerName#
    </td>
</tr>    
</script>
```

In my doc ready event I define the `userInfo` object:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var userInfo = $.parseJSON($.cookie('visitorData'));
```

When the datasource read returns data I get a js error which says `userInfo.UserId`is undefined. Is there some way to make my `userInfo` object available in the template? Is there some other way to go about this without having to define the userInfo in every item of the returned data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context is not the same. The scope in which you have defined the variable is not the same as the one in which the template is executed.

Create a global variable for the `userInfo` object, declare it outside the doc ready handler you shared.

Answer (score 3):

Variables in templates (afaik) need to be either part of the bound data or a global variable.

Try defining:

```
userInfo = $.parseJSON($.cookie('visitorData'));
$(document).ready(function () {

    ....
}
```

and the template as:

```
<script id="detailsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr class="row k-alt">
        <td>
            #= (OwnerId == userInfo.UserId)? "Me" : OwnerName #
        </td>
    </tr>    
</script>
```

Comment: You were close.. but in my case the variable needed to be declared outside the doc ready event.

Comment: !? Being global, is defined in `window`.

Comment: BTW: Does it work for you having "#" as opening in template instead of "#=". It does not for me.

Comment: @oniBai your code doesn't work. userInfo = $.parseJSON($.cookie('visitorData')); defined inside the doc ready doesn't work in the template.

Comment: Please, check the the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/FP2K7/. The problem is not about `userInfo` being global but about getting the value of the cookie inside `ready`.

Comment: You've edited your answer.. and yeah it works now. If userInfo is not defined outside of doc ready it doesn't work right? So your original answer wasn't clear in that you didn't show var userInfo o outside of the doc ready. There was no userInfo defined outside of it. Not trying to be a prick, i appreciate the response and you are correct.

Comment: Right! I paid attention to the fact that you didn't have access to `userInfo` as it was **but** I didn't realize that `$.cookie` prevented you from setting the value. You asked about `userInfo.UserId` being undefined but there were actually two reasons for it :-D

Answer (score 0):

using inline template with kendo grid

```
template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' #: defaultCost > "+self.range +"? 'disabled':'' #/>"
```

where self.range my page level vairable